# .NET 4.0 - Microsoft.Windows.Shell - where is it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm playing around with the examples for the Sofa V2.5, which is a WPF Docking framework.

These are VS2010, .NET 4.0.  In one project, there's a reference to a "Microsoft.Windows.Shell" assembly, which is unresolved.

When I open the Add Reference and look for .NET assemblies, I don't see Microsoft.Windows.Shell.  Why not?  I'm running VS2010 on Windows 7.  How can it be missing?  If it's not missing, why can't VS2010 see it?

Comment: I still don't understand how to install this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably included with this : [Ribbon (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx)

Comment: Ribbon is nowadays included in the BCL, System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon. No need to use the RibbonControlLibrary anymore

Comment: The question is specifically for .NET 4.0. This is not helpful for developers limited by the older framework.

Answer (score 23):

It has a NuGet package now:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Windows.Shell
```

**Update June 2020:** Based on update provided by @yaron in the comments, this package is no longer available. As the NuGet page states:

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Thank you for this! However, after running this, how do I get it to show in "Extensions" under "add a reference"?

Comment: Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Windows.Shell'

Answer (score 4):

Get it from NuGet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Windows.Shell -Version 3.0.1
```

Note the addition of `-Version 3.0.1`, without this addition an error will be received.

Answer (score 3):

The package owner (Gareth Evans) decided to un-list it, but it's still available.
I would not recommend using it however.
This version is out-dated and may contain some kind of bug or vulnerability.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Shell/3.0.1

For the time-being, the accepted answer is still a valid option.
I wouldn't be surprised if the links quit working any day now though.
The .msi installer file will put stuff in `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Ribbon for WPF\`
Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll v3.5.41019.1 will be in the WindowChrome dir.

> Side note:
> Don't waste your time trying to use Microsoft Ribbon for WPF. It's a nightmare.
> There are much better options such as https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon
>
> Also, I find it telling that Fluent Ribbon uses https://github.com/ControlzEx/ControlzEx in place of Microsoft.Windows.Shell (ControlzEx includes source for the shell functions instead)

If the accepted answer's links quit working an alternative is to get the Multilingual App Toolkit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-mat
At the time of writing, it includes the same version (3.5.41019.1) and seems as though it will be supported into the future. (supports VS2019, has translation services and customers that rely on it, recommended for UWP app localization, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

`System.Windows.Shell` is the same as `Microsoft.Windows.Shell`. `System.Windows.Shell` is included in `PresentationFramework.dll`. 
So, in your .xaml file, use the class in the namespace directly. In your codebehind use the class in the namespace include 'using System.Windows.Shell;'.

Extend：
WindowsChrome available since .net4.5
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Shell;assembly=PresentationFramework"

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Visual Studio
go to

Tools>>NuGet Package Manager>>Package Manager Console

type this in the Package Manager Console window

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Windows.Shell -Version 3.0.1
```